# what does the apostrophe mean in this notation?

Tags: theory, notation, intervals

Found this whilst reading some basic theory on wikipedia, but am trying to figure out what the supposed meaning is.

example: b-c'   kleine secunde  16:15
source: [Wikipedia link with interval table](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(muziek)) ( dutch )

Rest of the table has some references with apostrophe, and some without, from what i can gather its only on small intervals ( i.e. minor second, minor third, diminished fifth )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can conclude from that web page's "Moderne naamgeving" section, the apostrophe denotes a note in a higher octave, assuming that the C notes determine octave boundaries. Note that the perfect unison is merely " c-c " and the perfect octave is " c-c' " there.

Comment: To round out this answer, the apostrophe here is about the next octave up, not the absolute octave of the `A` `a` `a'` `a''` `a'''` series with `a'` being the 440Hz `a` note which I first though about in the `b - c'` example.

Answer (score 6):

As @Dekkadeci says, the primes refer to the next octave. The lower octave would be indicated by a comma: c, .

This is the notation used in LilyPond, http://lilypond.org/index.html, which is a program of Dutch origin.

[image]